# "error": [{ "code": 404, "message": "Request does not match any route."}] error magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, 404, get

for custom get api request i am getting "Request does not match any route." error

api.xml

```
<route_entity>
    <route>/servicebms/outgoingcall/:k_number/:agent_number/:customer_number/:caller_id/:created_time</route>
    <action_type>entity</action_type>
</route_entity>
```

Here is the url

http://15.206.238.137/api/rest/servicebms/outgoingcall/

and how to add authentacation key, x-api-key in magento

Comment: Please follow the reference link, it will help you to fix this issue.
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-magento-custom-api/

Comment: @Nits But i am using REST API, in that post method is working fine, but get method is giving error.